# If I was there, I am not alive now or I would not be alive now.(indicative or subjunctive usage)

Tags: subjunctives, sentence-usage, verb-usage

> 1. **If I was there yesterday,** I am not alive now or I would not be alive now.

> 2. **If I had been there yesterday**, I am not alive now or I would not be alive now.

Which one between 1 and 2 is more widely used among native English speakers?

p.s.: The focus of the question is : If I was there vs. If I had been there

Comment: If I am not alive now, how can I speak?

Comment: Because I was not there yesterday, I am alive now.

Comment: The meaning of the examples is weird and distracting attention away from its structure. Obviously the speaker was alive **yesterday** otherwise they would not be speaking today. The speaker was not born today. Try to come up with a more meaningful example, e.g. "*If I was/had been there I **would have seen** you*."

Comment: *"If I was/had been there yesterday I **wouldn't** be alive today."* makes more logical sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the examples quoted are evidently made up and so paradoxical, so as to be unhelpful to any visitor in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native English speakers would say

> If I had been there yesterday, I would not be alive now.

You could change **now** to **today** as both are talking about days and it sounds more natural.

Comment: That is the only choice for the likely meaning intended.